# How to cede overlapping area in polygons in QGIS to one of the polygons based on a condition

Tags: polygon, qgis, overlapping, multipolygons

I have a shape file with 2745 individual sites/polygons in the Philippines, each site represents a tree planting project, with relevant information (30 attributes to be precise), including the year the site was planted. However, in QGIS using the Topology Checker, I have identified 167 cases of overlap across sites. I need to fix this so that I do not 'double-count' pixels later when I do my analyses. I'm trying to figure out how to 'cede' the intersection of overlapping polygons to the respective site that was plant earliest in time, ie I have a site that was planted in 2017 whose area = a+b, and another site planted in 2018 whose area is b+c, and so in this case I'd want the 'b' (the intersection/overlap) to go to just the 2017 site. There are some cases where there's 3 sites that overlap, or one site overlaps with two sites separately, and also a few cases where one site is completely enclaved by another. I've been trying to do this for ages in R to no success, so I'm seeing how I can do this in QGIS. I tried dissolving the layer whilst leaving the attribute blank so that it would do it simply on geometry, but it just merged all 2745 into 1. Ideally, I also want the site that keeps the 'b' to add to the column "planting_effort_years" to add +1 for each site that overlaps onto it. Any advice on this would be much appreciated, please. If it is relevant, some of the sites have just one polygon, others are multipolygons. I'm adding here some screenshots to visualize some of the overlap error types: [image: Typical error where sites overlap: the red = b, the orange = a, and green =c] [image: This is one of the more challenging ones, since the green site is overlapping with two other sites (the northern and southern orange ones, once again the red bits are the overlaps] [image: And finally, this a case where the green site=a+b, but the 'orange' site is just b and therefore shows up entirely red]

Comment: 1. Get rid of multipart polygons - never use these for analysis. 2. Smash all the polygons together with a union intersect called an Integrated Terrain Mapping Unit (ITMU). So you have a single layer of polygon parts, of every boundary and overlaps. Now you can run a query on all the mini parts to find the oldest date attribute and set a winner area name. Now dissolve all at once by winner name.